# Is my proof that $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n+\frac{10100}{n}}$ is convergent valid?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to answer whether the following series is convergent or divergent:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n+\frac{10100}{n}}$$

Alternating series test seems like a good idea. So if I prove that $\frac{1}{n+\frac{10100}{n}}$ is monotone for large $n$ and converges to $0$ then I'm done. Convergence to $0$ is trivial so all I need to do is to prove that the sequence is monotone, for sufficiently large $n$. Here is what I've done:

$\frac{1}{n+1+\frac{10100}{n+1}}-\frac{1}{n+\frac{10100}{n}}=\frac{n+\frac{10100}{n}-n-1-\frac{10100}{n+1}}{(n+1+\frac{10100}{n+1})(n+\frac{10100}{n})}$

The denominator is always positive so I'm only examining the numerator now.

$n+\frac{10100}{n}-n-1-\frac{10100}{n+1}=\frac{10100(n+1)-10100n-n(n+1)}{n(n+1)}$

Again, the denominator is always positive, so let's examine the numerator.

$10100(n+1)-10100n-n(n+1)=10100-n^2-n=10100-(n^2+n)$ which is less than zero for sufficiently large $n$. That means that for sufficiently large $n$ the sequence is monotonely decreasing so we can finish by saying our series is convergent by alternating series test.

Is everything correct with my logic? Could this be done simpler?

Comment: It is correct. I think it is also the simplest way to do. You can compute the derivative of $x/(x^2+10100)$ and study its sign (but is essentially the same).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic is fine. I would look at the denominators $d_k$. If $n\gt 10100$, we have $d_n\lt n+1$. But $d_{n+1}\gt n+1$. So after $10100$  (the absolute values of) the terms are decreasing.  Quicker, and a lot easier to type!